# Why must the attenuation coefficient of a medium be negative?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

So I am studying wave propagation in a medium and it seems like every derivation assumes that the attenuation coefficient is always positive however I can't seem to find an explanation.

I a vague sense that this it must be positive because else it would violate conservation of energy by considering the poynting vector, however I can't seem to formulate an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is often assumed that the fractional change in the amplitude of a wave $\dfrac{A(x+\Delta x)-A(x)}{A(x)}$ in moving from position $x$ to position $x+\Delta x$ is proportional to $\Delta x$.

$\dfrac{A(x+\Delta x)-A(x)}{A(x)} \propto \Delta x$

Assuming there are no sources, $A(x+\Delta x)<A(x)$ and so the right-hand side of the equation will be negative.

That being the case a negative constant of proportionality is introduced on the right-hand side of the equation, $-k$, where the attenuation constant, $k$,  has a positive value.

Integration of the expression above leads to the equation $A(x) = A(0) e^{-kx}$ where $k$ depends on the propagating medium, frequency etc.